# Does Visual Studio 2022 Community currently support F#?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Having just loaded Visual Studio Community 2022, I find I am unable to load F# projects created in VS Community 2019 and all the project templates for F# seem to be missing.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it does. Do you have .NET installed?

Comment: Did you check F# when you ran the installer? It is not checked by default.

Comment: F# is checked by default. "F# desktop language support" (microsoft-speak for legacy stuff) is not on by default, nor is any legacy stuff for C# at this point.

Answer (score 3):

It does. Make sure you have all the F# components checked in the installer:

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite accurate. F# support comes out of the box when you install .NET, and only "F# desktop language support" needs to be explicitly checked. All that does is give you the ability to create legacy F# desktop app projects. Modern .NET comes with F# by default in all environments.

Comment: OK, but "F# language support" still needs to be checked, right? OP could've cleared it somehow. I'm just trying to point him to the right place in the installer to look.

Comment: Perhaps, although that would be weird. It is checked by default on any install. You can't remove F# support from your machine even if you uncheck it. It's literally a part of the .NET SDK itself.

Comment: Does this also have the F# project templates?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: Thanks.  Will try again tomorrow…

Comment: It works!  For some reason, my initial installation kept showing an error of 
"Unable to load ...host". Going back and completely uninstalling the vs 2022 installation, and (fairly closely) following your above diagram (very helpful), all did install correctly. The 2019 projects --F#-- all loaded correctly, and the F# project templates are now present.  Thanks again!